# Google Analytics Evant Tracking Code Implementation

Tags: javascript, html, events, google-analytics

I recently implemented "Show number" option on my website, only in order to track how many users would be interested in Phone number of my clients. For Tracking this click/event i wanted to implement GA Event tracking so that i can read data in Google Analytics.

I implemented the GA snippet in my code but it does not seem to be working. i checked it on Live Event, and also i waited 48 hours to show in analytics which is sometimes suggested. Nothing happened. No tracked clicks for me. It doesnt work.

Where could i have made a mistake?

here is the code i use GA snippet in:

```
<div class="value" style="font-size: 14px;">
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-id="phone_{$seller_info.ID}" data-key="{$item.Key}" class="show_value" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'ShowNumber', 'ShowNumberDetails', '{$seller_info}');">{$item.value|truncate:4:''}*** <span title="{$lang.show_more_desc}">{$lang.show_num}</span></a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use ga() your GA implementation needs to be through analytics.js so it should look like this:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

If it looks like:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-31591889-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-31591889-1');
</script>
```

Then you're on gtag.js and you need to do events [this way](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events).

Also would be helpful to post any console errors when you click on that link. I tested it myself with a working analytics.js implementation and the data is sending fine:

[image]